# Git log is only showing last commit

Tags: reactjs, git, react-native, github

I'm working with React and React Native, using Yarn and Create React App. Create React App sits up a git repository. The problem is when I make commits to git, then I call 'git log', it only shows the most recent commit. Even if I call 'git log -all', it still only shows one commit. I've searched but haven't found another example of this problem.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Comment: You would want `--all`, not just `-all` (which means `-a -l -l`, which fails because `-l` needs a number). If you did type in `--all` (two hyphens), make sure you cut and paste the actual command and its output so that people can see it. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are calling `git log` from the Git bash, then you may need to page down through the log by pressing <kbd>↓</kbd>.  By default, the Git log will display the most recent commits at the top, as much as can fit in one screen.  If your window happens to be small and/or the first commit message happens to be long, then it could explain why you only see one commit by typing `git log` alone.

Comment: You're so right! I feel like a fool... lol.. for some reason it seems like I used to use the UP arrow to scroll through them. .. I never tried the DOWN arrow... Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What do you get when you invoke `git rev-parse HEAD~`?

If it results "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD~': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.", in fact there is only one commit.

Comment: A previous comment answered the question, it was just user error..lol. But, I very much appreciate your reply and I will keep it noted for future issues. Thanks!!